# One missing ingredient to show that $F(z)=\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$ with $F(z_0) = f'(z_0)$ is analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Suppose that $f$ is analytic on an open set $G$ and that $z_0 \in G$

Let $F(z)=\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$ $s.t.$ $z \neq z_0, F(z_0)=f'(z_0)$.

I want to show that $F$ is analytic on $G$.

My work so far:

$F(z)=\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0} \Rightarrow F'(z)=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{f(z+h)-f(z_0+h)}{z+h-z_0-h}-\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}}{h}=\lim_{h \rightarrow0}\frac{\frac{f(z+h)}{z-z_0}-\frac{f(z_0+h)}{z-z_0}-\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}+\frac{f(z_0}{z-z_0}}{h}=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{z-z_0}-\frac{f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}}{h}=\frac{f'(z)-f'(z_0)}{h}=\lim_{h \rightarrow } \frac{f'(z)-F(z_0)}{h}$ .

My question is how can I show that $f'(z)=F(z)$ so that I can finish this proof ?

Note: In the first version of this question it only said "differentiable" instead of "analytic" and this is what one of the answers is adressing.

Comment: Can you clarify: with differentiable you mean complex differentiable (analytic / holomorphic) right?

Comment: @Winther my apologies, yes I mean complex differentiable .

Comment: @Winther well I think that's what I mean , the question says just differentiable, but the course is complex analysis so i assume it means complex differentiation

Comment: Ok. I edited the question with this leaving a note about the original formulation as not to invalidate the answer below

Comment: @Winther the question itself doesn't actually say analytic though it just says differentiable, although it goes on to say consider the function f(x)=x|x| to show this is not true for real functions.

Comment: Analytic and complex differentiable is the same thing ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_complex_analysis ). And this is what they mean when they say differentiable

Comment: Do you know that analytic functions are infinitely differentiable (in the complex sense)?

Comment: @zwh I think I have been a bit confused , in the sense that I knew analytic functions were infinitely differentiable (as they give rise to Taylor series etc...) but did not know that all complex differentiable functions were infinitely differentiable and hence analytic.

Comment: @zwh in class we defined Cauchy's integral theorem as requiring f(z) to be differentiable although I believe a more common definition explicitly states the function to be analytic  ? which I suppose means the same thing in the complex sense then ?

Comment: The answer to your question really depends on the machinery you already have available to you at this point in your course.  Do you already have that holomorphic functions are analytic?  If you don't know that, do you know Morera's theorem?  These are the two ways I would think about this problem.

Comment: @StevenGubkin in class we defined them the same way as if f is differentiable on a disk $D(z_0,\epsilon$ centered at $z_0$ radius $\epsilon$ we say that f is holomorphic or analytic at $z_0$

Comment: Do you know that such functions are represented locally by their power series expansions yet?  Do you have Morera's theorem yet?

Comment: I knew that such functions can be expressed locally as a power series representation but I don't think I know Morera's theorem yet, unless it was stated without it's title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that directly. An approach such as yours would also work for real functions. But this is false over the reals. For instance, if $f\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is the function defined by$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2\sin\left(\frac1x\right)&\text{ if }x\neq0\\0&\text{ otherwise,}\end{cases}$$then $f$ is differentiable, but $\frac{f(x)}x$ isn't continuous.

Comment: Carlos Santos could I say that  $f(z)=F(z)h-f(z_0) \Rightarrow f'(z)= \frac{F(z+h)h-F(z_0)h-f(z_0+h)+f(z_0)}{h}=F'(z+h)-F(z_0)+f'(z_0)$ and so from our previous expression for F'(z) say $F'(z)=lim_{h \rightarrow}\frac{F(z+h)-F(z)+f'(z_0)-f'(z_0}{h}$

Comment: @exodius Again, if you could do it with arguments such as this one, it woud work for real functions too. But it **can't** work for real functions too, since the statement is false for real functions.

Comment: do you have any hints as to how I may proceed ?

Comment: @exodius Over $\mathbb C$, differentiable (on an open set) implies analytic and every analytic function has the property that you're trying to prove.

Comment: could we proceed by perhaps splitting it into two and using one of Cauchys theorems seems as how they would use that property ?

Comment: In your example, I would think you would want to show the associated $F$ is not differentiable.

Comment: @zhw Yes, I got confused. What I meant was that the associated function $F$ is not differentiable.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I actually think my approach might be correct in the context of the question , as I just realised the second part says take a function f(x)=x|x| to show that this isn't true for the reals